# Why aren't my old DLL's running with my app pool in 32bit mode?

Tags: iis, application-pools, 32bit-64bit, asp, windows-server-2008

I am moving my websites from a server 2003x86 environment to a server 2008x64. the 2008 server is using iis 7.5 and the app pool I am using is configured for 32bit mode.  I get an error 'Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'  Server.createObject failed.'  I beleive that it is in the DLL's that all the ASP sites point to.  My programmers, as usual, say it isn't code or the DLL's.  Am I missing something to make these old DLL's work?  By the way these sites are connecting to a SQL 2000 Database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get old DLL's running on 64bit server](http://serverfault.com/questions/151916/how-to-get-old-dlls-running-on-64bit-server)

Answer (score 0):

Given the dearth of specifics in your question, I can only make a educated guess.  Since you moved from Server03 to 08, I can only assume that you were using an older version of IIS.  That being said, you probably need to install the IIS 6 Management Compatibility add on that's found in the IIS role.

The ASP error you are getting is a pretty generic error that can be caused by a number of things from what I'm seeing on the search results, so if you want better answers you'll need to give more information about your setup, the code, etc.