# How to get old DLL's running on 64bit server

Tags: iis-7, iis-7.5, application-pools, 32bit-64bit

I'm moving my company's websites from a windows 2003x86 server to windows 2008x64 which is running IIS 7.5.

The problem that I've got is that all the DLL's which were running fine on the old server, now error out whenever they're called. All I get is a generic error like:

> Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'
>
> Server.CreateObject Failed
>
> /folder/scriptname.asp, line 24
>
> 800401f3

The line that errors is:

```
'23 lines of comments  
set A0SQL_DATA = server.createobject("olddllname.Data")  
'the rest of the script
```

I already have that site running in an App Pool that is set to 32bit mode. But, I get the error anyway.

Has anyone experienced this? I'm frusterated because all the info I look up says that all I need to do is set the app pool to run in 32bit mode. I did that and It's still not working.
What else could I check?

Comment: dupe of http://serverfault.com/questions/151876/why-arent-my-old-dlls-running-with-my-app-pool-in-32bit-mode, although this is worded better

Comment: It is a dupe but as this one is better worded I've voted to close 151876.

Comment: Sorry about this being a dupe. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

From [here](http://kb.monitorware.com/server-object-error-asp-0177-800401f3-t900.html) if found this:

> This error means "Invalid class
> string" -- in other words the call to
> CreateObject failed because the name
> object cannot be found by the OLE
> sub-system. Causes include:
>
> You really didn't run regsvr32 on the server after all.
>
> You ran regsvr32 but
> it reported an error.
>
> Someone modified
> security on part of the registry
> that's preventing the OLE subsystem
> from reading all or part of the
> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT tree.
>
> The name of
> the object you are trying to create
> was mispelled or is incorrect.
>
> Determine if it's a permissions
> problem

Also, since you're migrating from 03 to 08, have you installed the IIS 6 Management Compatibility add on that's found in the IIS role?  I'm not an expert on IIS or ASP, so I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll research those causes you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is that your DLL is a 32-bit DLL and the Application Pools is running in 64 bit. 
What you will need to do is change the Application Pool where your application is running to be a 32-bit application pool. See enable32BitAppOnWin64 at: http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add

You can do that in the UI by selecting the Application Pool in the list of AppPools (select the Tree node) and use the Advanced Settings to enable that.